# Hibernate filter for update?

Tags: hibernate, filter

how can I restrict updates of domain restricted data?

Let's say I have users of my hibernate application, which are allowed to see all contracts of a specific country (i.e. filter: country='US')

How can I ensure, that this user can only insert new records with country='US'?

Is there a something like 'a filter to restrict update statements' in hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this at the Hibernate layer by implementing a [PreUpdateListener / PreInsertListener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html)  and veto the update, but this would probably be over-kill in most cases.

I would only do this if this was critical for security reasons and would have this *in addition to* validation logic closer to the View or Controller layer. You don't mention what kind of application this is, but pretty much all UI frameworks (web, desktop or mobile) have validation support which will make it more convenient to handle this sort of logic (as opposed to handling exceptions from the persistence layer).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to handle the check in your DAO for example:

```
    public void saveContract(Contract contract, String countryCode) {

    if (contract.getCountryCode().equals(countryCode)) {
     threw InvalidContractException
   } else {
     saveContract(contract) }

    private void saveContract(Contract contract)
```

I do not think that it can be checked declaratively.

If users are authenticated at DB level ie. each app. user has it's own db  user, then you can create a table

db_user, ctry

and refer the to this table in the contract mapping using ?!

or you can use a virtual private database